# PHP console invert scroll when printing multiple lines

Tags: php, linux, terminal, console

I'm writing a PHP script (think matrix) that will run on command line only.

At the moment it prints a line of code that ends in a new line, over and over. When the screen fills it begins to scroll with each line. The scroll direction is from the bottom to the top.

Is there anyway using cursor position in a terminal to be able to invert this behaviour and begin printing lines of code at the top of the screen so that the scroll is from top to bottom?

*Example code:*

```
for ($lines=1000;$lines>0;$lines--) {
    echo "this is a basic line of code\n";
}
```

*What I'm trying:*

```
for ($lines=1000;$lines>0;$lines--) {
    echo "\033[0;0H";        
    echo "\nthis is a basic line of code";
}
```

This is a very basic example that simulates what I'm trying to achieve - php print a line at position 0,0. Write new line at 0,0, old line moves down one line. When repeated over and over the scroll would then be inverted.

There may be other ways that I'm unaware of to do this other than using **[ANSI](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes)**?

*For the 'terminals will be different depending OS' comment that is bound to appear --- I'm using a mac and it's a fun little project so that's all it needs to support*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from ANSI (or something based on curses), you have few alternatives.  Here's an ANSI example:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
for ( $lines = 1000; $lines > 0; $lines-- ) {
        echo "This is line $lines of output\r";
        echo "\033[T\033[A";
}
?>
```

It prints each line, then moves the cursor to the left margin on *that* line, prints a reverse-index (`\033[T`) and then moves the cursor up to the newly blank line (`\033[A`).  It works with Terminal.app

Interestingly, the [php binding for ncurses](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ncurses.php) doesn't provide a terminfo interface (unlike most other language bindings).